# WP_Query returning wrong result

Tags: php, wordpress

My plugin adds a custom post type to wordpress, and id like to display all posts that have been published. I use wp_query to display all posts but it seems to fetch all post regardless of their status. Have I forgotten something ?

Note that status changes from publish to draft, I use wp_update_post() to edit the post status .
here is my code :

Loop :

```
function jobs_list_loop() {
    global $paged;
    //$curpage = $paged ? $paged : 1;
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
                        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
                } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
                        $paged = get_query_var('page');
                } else {
                        $paged = 1;
                }
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'job',
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'posts_per_page' => POST_PER_PAGE,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    $curpage = $paged;
    if($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="quote">    
    <?php
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array($image_width,$image_height));
    the_content();
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    endwhile;
        echo '
        <div id="wp_pagination">
            <a class="first page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link(1).'">&laquo;</a>
            <a class="previous page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link(($curpage-1 > 0 ? $curpage-1 : 1)).'">&lsaquo;</a>';
            for($i=1;$i<=$query->max_num_pages;$i++)
                echo '<a class="'.($i == $curpage ? 'active ' : '').'page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'">'.$i.'</a>';
            echo '
            <a class="next page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link(($curpage+1 <= $query->max_num_pages ? $curpage+1 : $query->max_num_pages)).'">&rsaquo;</a>
            <a class="last page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link($query->max_num_pages).'">&raquo;</a>
        </div>
        ';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

Here is the code used to change status from publish to draft :

```
  $jb_post = array(
      'ID' => $id,
      'post_status' => 'draft'
  );
  wp_update_post( $jb_post );
```

Note that if I change to query to fetch only drafts, or trash or whatever it will do it successfuly.
Am i forgetting something ? I have made tons of research and can't find anything giving a suitable answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Should it have been wp_update_post( $jb_post ) instead?  The query arguments look right, can you confirm that the posts are actually published in the database?

Comment: It is maent to be $jb_post, I edited teh code and forgot this.. Concerning the db, the value goes from publish to Draft in the db, no problem with that, this result in showing "This post does no exist" in the loop

Comment: To be honest I could just control the post_status value for each post and then chose to display or not dependign on the value, but I feel I'm missing something, i don't want to start tweeking such a silly code...